# Toggle in React not Toggling all elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, memory, toggle

So upon clicking it only toggles one card back over. So the toggle is being read correctly in my functions but I do not understand why it is not flipping both cards back over it only flips the card at position [1] in my array and position[0] is unaffected when just flipping cards false in the flip function it flips both cards but it seems when I set the array I am missing something. also if I try to do something like cardChoiceId[0].setToggle(false) I get a type error saying not a function so that is not the solution  here is the code

```
import bg from '../images/card-bg.png'

let cardChoiceId = []
let cardsWon = []

const GameCard = ({ img, name, num, setScore, setResult, cardArray }) => {
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)




    const checkForMatch = () => {
        if (cardChoiceId[0] === cardChoiceId[1]) {
            alert(`That's a Match`)
            setToggle(true)
            cardsWon.push(cardChoiceId)
            cardChoiceId = []
            setScore(+1)
            if (cardsWon.length === cardArray.length) {
                setResult(` Congratz!!! You Win `)
            }   
        }
        else {
            setToggle(false)
            cardChoiceId = []
        }   
    }

    const flip = () => {
        setToggle(!false)
        cardChoiceId.push(name)
        console.log(cardChoiceId)
        if (cardChoiceId.length === 2) {
            return setTimeout(checkForMatch, 500)
        }

    }



    return toggle === false ? (
            <div onClick={flip}>
                <div className='game-card-bg' >
                    <img src={bg} alt='card' style={{ width: '100%' }} />
                </div>
             </div>
            ):(
            <div>
        <div className='game-card' >
            <img src={img} alt='card' />
            <h4 className='card-name'>{name}</h4>
        </div>  
    </div>
    )

}

export default GameCard
```

Comment: Can you show the code of `cardChoiceId` where you handling it outside the GameCard component?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you try to manage the game state alongside within the local component state and mix component state patterns with global state (``cardChoiceId` etc). Let me make it more clear, you should follow [seperation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle.

You got **game** state that should keep track on how many cards are toggeled/flipped and check if they match.

You got **local** state of the `GameCard` component that is responsible for rendering the game card in either state (toggeled or not). In the first place it might seem that your local state should manage the toggle state, but your global state depends on the toggle state, so it must be 'pulled up'. Hence, there is no local state in the `GameCard`.

I would rather suggest that the outer component should tell it if it is flipped and also the outer component should provide a callback that the component can use to inform the outer component about a click event. Note how it becomes much easier to reason about what is happening per component:

First, think of the states that a card can be in, to me this would be:

```
const CardState = {
  HIDDEN: 0,
  FLIPPED: 1,
  WON: 2,
};
```

Let's assume a `cardArray` to be a shuffled array of cards where every name occurs twice

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Tiger',
    img: '...',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Lion',
    img: '...',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Tiger',
    img: '...',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Lion',
    img: '...',
  },
  ...
]
```

Now, we can implement our `Game` logic, but we do not care how to display a card itself. We only care for the logic here.

```
const Game = ({ cardArray }) => {
  // keep track of every cards state
  const [cardState, setCardState] = useState(
    // initialize every card as HIDDEN
    cardArray.reduce((a, c) => ({
      ...a,
      [c.id]: {
        ...c, // all card info
        state: CardState.HIDDEN, // add state
      },
    }, {})
  );

  // set the new state of a specific card
  const updateState = (id, newState) => setCardState(prev => {
    ...prev, // keep state of all cards
    [id]: {
      ...prev[id],
      state: newState, // update state of id
    },
  });

  // check if all cards are WON
  const checkGameOver = () => {
    const notWonCard = Object.values(cardState)
      .find(card => card.state !== CardState.WON);
    if (!notWonCard /* ===  all won*/) {
      alert(` Congratz!!! You Win `);
    }
  };

  // checks if two FLIPPED cards match and if so, set them both WON, in this case also trigger a checkGameOver
  const checkForMatch = () => {
    const flippedCards = Object.values(cardState)
      .filter(card => card.state === CardState.FLIPPED);
    if (flippedCards.length === 2) {
      if (flippedCards[0].name === flippedCards[1].name) {
        alert(`That's a Match`);
        updateState(flippedCards[0].id, CardState.WON);
        updateState(flippedCards[1].id, CardState.WON);
        setTimeout(checkGameOver, 500);
      }
    }
  };

  // update the state of a card depending on its current state and trigger checkForMatch
  const onCardClick = id => {
    switch (cardState[id].state) {
      case CardState.FLIPPED: {
        updateState(id, CardState.HIDDEN);
        break;
      }
      case CardState.HIDDEN: {
        updateState(id, CardState.FLIPPED);
        setTimeout(checkForMatch, 500);
        break;
      }
      case CardState.WON: 
        // fallthrough
      default: {
        // noop
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {cardArray.map(card => (
        <GameCard
          key={card.id}
          name={card.name}
          img={card.img}
          isFlipped={
            cardState[card.id] === CardState.FLIPPED
              || cardState[card.id] === CardState.WON
          }
          onClick={() => onCardClick(card.id)}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now that the logic is done, we can keep our head free of it to think of how the actual card should render:

```
import bg from '...';
const GameCard = ({ name, img, isFlipped, onClick }) => (
  isFlipped
  ? (
    <div>
      <div className='game-card' >
        <img src={img} alt='card' />
        <h4 className='card-name'>{name}</h4>
      </div>  
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div onClick={onClick}>
      <div className='game-card-bg' >
        <img src={bg} alt='card' style={{ width: '100%' }} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
);
```

It is not tested code, but rather should give you an idea of seperation of concerns.

Comment: thank you I was unclear on how to approach this I knew it had to be due to that some way or another...will let you know how it turns out

Answer (score 0):

I can only provide working code thought this was another answer...so sorry ya'll this is why it is important to make sure you answer things on a public forum like this right away....but here is the working code not sure how I solved it may edit this later when I have more time....

board logic

```
  const [cards, setCards] = useState(props.cards)
  const [checkers, setCheckers] = useState([])
  const [completed, setCompleted] = useState([])
  const onCardClick = card => () => {
    if (checkersFull(checkers) || cardAlreadyInCheckers(checkers, card)) return
    const newCheckers = [...checkers, card]
    setCheckers(newCheckers)
    const cardsInCheckersMatched = validateCheckers(newCheckers)
    if (cardsInCheckersMatched) {
      setCompleted([...completed, newCheckers[0].type])
    }
    if (checkersFull(newCheckers)) {
      resetCheckersAfter(1000)
    }
    function validateCheckers(checkers){
      return checkers.length === 2 &&
      checkers[0].type === checkers[1].type
    }
    function cardAlreadyInCheckers(checkers, card){
      return checkers.length === 1 && checkers[0].id === card.id
    }
    function checkersFull(checkers){
      return checkers.length === 2
    }
    function resetCheckersAfter(time) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setCheckers([])
      }, time)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const newCards = cards.map(card => ({
      ...card,
      flipped:
        checkers.find(c => c.id === card.id) ||
        completed.includes(card.type),
    }))
        setCards(newCards)
        //eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [checkers, completed])

  return (
    <div className="Board">
      {cards.map(card => (
        <Card {...card} onClick={onCardClick(card)} key={card.id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Card Logic

`````
    const images = {duck, pig, horse, cat, dog, dolphin, fish, roo, lion, frog }
    const cards = Object.keys(images).reduce((result, item) => {
        const getCard = () => ({
            id: id++,
            type: item,
            backImg,
            frontImg: images[item],
            flipped: false,
        })
        return [...result, getCard(), getCard()]
    }, [])
    return shuffle(cards)
}

const shuffle=(arr) =>{
    let len = arr.length
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        let randomIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * len)
        let copyCurrent = { ...arr[i] }
        let copyRandom = { ...arr[randomIdx] }
        arr[i] = copyRandom
        arr[randomIdx] = copyCurrent
    }
    return arr
}
    const cards = buildCards()````
`````